# Mysterious crash with CoreTelephony on iPad thus not included

Tags: ios, crash, cocoapods, core-telephony, reachability-swift

I need help to find a significant crash in out app. It has occurred after we switched from Carthage to Cocoapods and since we don't have CoreTelephony linked in out app, I assume it's a pod that's using it.
But to be fair; I have no idea if that's the case.

This is the symbolicated crash report from iTunesConnect:
[image]

It primarily occurs on iPad, but also sporadically on iPhone.
Only on iOS 9.3.5 and iOS 10.x
There are MANY crashes - approx. 16% of the users, so this is not a rare bug.

Since I suspect a pod, this is our podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'


platform :ios, '9.0'
# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!


target 'Secret App TopShelf' do
    platform :tvos, '9.2'
    # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!

    pod 'RxSwift',    '~> 4.0'
    pod 'CoreBrick', '~> 4.0.2'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '4.2'
    pod 'HTTPStatusCodes', '3.2'
    pod 'RxCocoa',    '~> 4.0'
    pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '4.3'

end

target 'Secret App iOS' do
    use_frameworks!

    pod 'RxSwiftExt'
    pod 'ParentalGate', '1.1.1'
    pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '4.3'
    pod 'HTTPStatusCodes', '3.2'
    pod 'ThePerfectApp', '4.8'
    pod 'TrackingBrick', '2.6.1'
    pod 'AdobeMobileSDK', '~> 4.17'
    pod 'RxSwift',    '~> 4.0'
    pod 'RxCocoa',    '~> 4.0'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '4.2'
    pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'RxGesture'
end

target 'Secret App iOS Tests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for testing
end

target 'Secret App iOS UI Tests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for testing
end

target 'Secret App tvOS' do
    platform :tvos, '9.2'
    # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!

    pod 'RxSwift',    '~> 4.0'
    pod 'CoreBrick', '~> 4.0.2'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '4.2'
    pod 'HTTPStatusCodes', '3.2'
    pod 'RxCocoa',    '~> 4.0'
    pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '4.3'
    pod 'RxSwiftExt'
    pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 4.0'

end

target 'Secret App tvOS Tests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for testing
end

target 'Secret App tvOS UI Tests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for testing
end
```

I have read on the internet that,

> There is an iOS bug that causes instances of the CTTelephonyNetworkInfo class to sometimes get notifications after they have been deallocated. Instead of instantiating, using, and releasing instances you must instead retain and never release them to work around the bug.

But I have no idea where the reference to CoreTelephony should be.
There is no usage of CTTelephonyNetworkInfo in the code.

Hope you guys are able to point me in ANY direction with this.

Thanks.

Update:
After investigating some more I have learned that:

- Using Ashley Mills ReachabilitySwift v. 4.3.0 does not include CoreTelephony
- Using ReachabilitySwift v. 4.3.1 does indeed include CoreTelephony

Looking at [this bug](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift/issues/317) I'm starting to believe that the crash is caused by reachability trying to access CoreTelephony when it's not there.
As stated in the bug I have now tried to manually add the CoreTelephony and allow access to wifi information.
I will update with the results.

Comment: You could grep the Pods directory for Telephony to see which Pod is adding it to an xcconfig file.

Comment: You should also provide the full stack, including what is occurring on different threads to see if there is any trace of your actual client code.  Organizer/Crashes has a really good output for this to add to this question.

Comment: This is all there is. And that’s what’s puzzeling me. Because I agree, normally the stack trace is longer and has a trace of my apps code.

Comment: Issues updated with more info.